# Genymotion not loading virtual machine on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I recently successfully installed Virtualbox and Genymotion on Ubuntu. Everything was successful except for one thing. When I try to play the virtual machine,this is the output -

Unable to load VirtualBox engine.

Make sure that you have installed it correctly before starting Genymotion.

For more information refer to: https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#vbox

How can I fix this issue so that I will be able to run my virtual devices.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Force VirtualBox Module compilation by running following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Before running above command make sure that you are in `vboxuser` group. To do this run following command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers angel
```

Here `angel` is my username, replace this with your username.